# Cpp Delete memory

Tags: c++

I'm trying to delete all object from my memory but I'm not sure what also to delete and whats the best way.

```
void createAss(Object& object) {
  Ass a1 = Ass("asdf");
  Ass a2 = Ass("aaa");

  object.addAss(a1);
  object.addAss(a2);
}

int main(void) {
  Object obj("header");

  createAss(obj);

  return 0;
}
```

So my main question is do I have to `delete` a1, a2 and obj within the main function or should it be done by the Destructor of the certain class?

Comment: _"So my main question is do I have to delete a1, a2"_ In short: No!

Comment: It should be (and is automatically) done by the destructor.

Comment: Read about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) & [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)

Comment: The problem seems to be answered in [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope). Depends, on what the declaration/definition of `Object::addAss(Ass);` actually is.

Comment: You haven't created it with pointers and `new`, so you can't use `delete`. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of `main()`, all its local objects are destroyed by their respective destructor.  That's what happens automatically to `obj`.  You do not need to delete anything, nor call the destructor.  The compiler will take care.

THe question is related to the definition of `Object` and more precisely, the implementation of `addAss()` and of `~Object()`:

- If `addAss()` uses `new` to create a copy of the object passed as argument, then `~Object()` should of course delete them.
- If you use some std containers, to store these objects, the destructor of the container will take care of the necessary destruction.

***Remark:***

Your statement  `Ass a1 = Ass("asdf");` is correct.  But as you speak of `delete` I'd like to clarify that this statement does not create a pointer:  You just create a local `a1` object that is initialised with the contructor `Ass("asdf")`.  It will be automatically destroyed when leaving `createAss()`.

Comment: `Ass a1("asdf")` would be a lot better